# Unity 3 - The type name or alias xxxx could not be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration, unity-container

I've read through several related questions here and I still can't seem to get my Unity XML configuration to work.

Here is my configuration file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly name="System.Security" />
    <namespace name="System.Security.Cryptography" />
    <container name="Default">
        <register type="HashAlgorithm" mapTo="SHA256Managed" />
        <register type="SymmetricAlgorithm" mapTo="AesCryptoServiceProvider" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

And the error message I get is ...

> The type name or alias **AesCryptoServiceProvider** could not be resolved.
>   Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

The HashAlgorithm is resolving normally, just not the AES provider.

The **System.Security** assembly is referenced in my project, and the **SymmetricAlgorithm** type can be resolved if I do ...

```
IUnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer ();

Container.RegisterType<SymmetricAlgorithm, AesCryptoServiceProvider> ();
```

... but I'd like to keep the configuration out of the code if possible.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`AesCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) is not located in `System.Security`. You will find it in the `System.Core` assembly instead.

So you need to fix your unity configuration to also include that assembly as in:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <namespace name="System.Security.Cryptography" />
  <assembly name="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <container name="Default">
    <register type="HashAlgorithm" mapTo="SHA256Managed" />
    <register type="SymmetricAlgorithm" mapTo="AesCryptoServiceProvider" />
  </container>
</unity>
```

**Note:** you will need to provide the full name of the assembly (with version, culture and token). This is because Unity will just concatenate the namespaces and assembly names with the type names, then it will check if the resulting type exists (check the [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507491(v=pandp.30).aspx)). When loading types using its name, most of the times you will need the fully qualified name, see for example the remark about the type name in [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace